# sed stripping hex from start of file including pattern

Tags: sed

I've been at this most of this afternoon hacking with `sed` and it's a bit of a minefield.

I have a file of hex of the form:

```
485454502F312E31203230300D0A0D0AFFD8FFE000104A46494600
```

I'm pattern matching on `0D0A0D0A` and have managed to delete the contents from the start of the file to there. The problem is that it leaves the `0D0A0D0A`, so I have to do a second pass to pick that up.

Is there a way in one command to delete up to and including the pattern that you match to and save it back into the same file ?

thanks in advance.

ID

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide better description of your problem.

Based on what you wrote you can use `-i` switch (Edit files in-place) of sed to save the changed file:

```
sed -i.bak 's/^.*0D0A0D0A//' file
```

PS: On posix and on some older versions of sed doesn't have `-i` switch available. If that's the case use it like this:

```
sed 's/^.*0D0A0D0A//' file > _temp && mv _temp file
```

Comment: `-i` is not posix. But however, thx for pointing me towards the option's `SUFFIX` argument. I have not up-voted as I currently don't see how your command will solve the problem. OP wants to delete lines in one run.. (I cannot imagine why this should fail, he just gave insufficient input, that's why I don't answered here)

Comment: That's right @hek2mgl I will make a comment in my question about it.

Comment: thanks. more or less got there with the answer above. but will wrap it in a script instead to rename the temp file back to the original file name.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
sed -e 's/.*0D0A0D0A//' file.txt
```

Comment: thanks. i've got mainly there with that one. just need to redirect from stdout.